# SSH protocol banner is a kind of DOS?

Tags: ssh, denial-of-service

In my test environment with Python script I generate on a target server:

```
SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

simply opening/closing a sufficient number of ssh connection.

Is it classified as a DOS attack against sshd?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is not classified as DoS attack but I think yes, this could cause DoS if you are able to generate enough traffic. To protect this you can use something like [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

I would say, as long you are not killing SSH daemon it is a stress test. Check the following settings in sshd config: MaxSessions and MaxStartups.

Comment: Very useful thanks, but you consider that whatever are the values MaxSessions and MaxStartups I can easily saturate them with the Python script.